# Writing a sonnet for high school, need help

Tags: grammaticality

The line is:
"At my hopes, at my dreams, and at my kind"
Can kind be used in this syntax? And did I use syntax properly?

Comment: *Kind* can mean many things.  What are you trying to communicate?

Comment: As in my ability to be kind to others.

Comment: In that sense, *kind* is an adjective.  You need the noun *kindness* to make it understandable, and to make it match *hopes* and *dreams*.

Comment: Single-syllable words similar to *kindness* include *grace* and *love*.

Comment: Thanks man, that helps a lot. English is weird so I was hoping that I could get away with it.

Comment: "at MY kind" doesn't work in that sentence (BTW that's a fragment sentence. If you said, I will work, at my hopes, dreams, and ability to show kindness. Or relate it however the rest of the lines connect, it would be correct

Comment: I think the beginning of the line has some iambic pentameter problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn the nouns

> **hopes, dreams,**

into verbs:   *I hope, when I hope, to hope* and *I dream, to dream*

then you have several options with the adjective **kind**

*be kind, prove kind,  to be not unkind.*

Comment: English is weird.